# Will Cokin-Z and HiTech 100mmx150mm filters fit on a Lee Holder?

Tags: filters, lee

I have a bunch of Cokin Z and HiTech filters.  I may be able to get my hands on a Lee Foundation Kit.  Would these filters fit into the Lee?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes. The 100mm filter size is common across the brands, but the parts in the actual holder system is not interchangeable. If you're really not sure, just bring a filter with you to the store and try it.

Comment: The thickness of the filters may matter. There are a variety of filter thicknesses, however the Lee Holder is capable of being modified to handle anything from 1mm to 4mm thickness, I believe. You can buy additional guide rails and screws to configure the system to hold anywhere from 1-4 1mm-4mm thick 100mm slides.

Comment: @jrista - That's why I suggested he bring one. I think he's fine, in general, but it's not like these are immovable objects you can't take to the store... ;)

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. The Lee holder defaults to 2mm filter support. If any of the others are 1, 3, or 4mm thick, the Lee holder in a store won't hold them right, but would still be compatible with a couple bits of extra hardware (which cost about $2 for alternate slide guides and $1 for alternate screws.)

Comment: @jrista - Cokin Z are 2mm thick normally.