# Can I use Cokin filters of Z-Pro version on Lee 100mm system?

Tags: filters, lee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Cokin-Z and HiTech 100mmx150mm filters fit on a Lee Holder?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21368/will-cokin-z-and-hitech-100mmx150mm-filters-fit-on-a-lee-holder)

Can I use Cokin filters of Z-Pro version on Lee 100mm system (I mean thickness)? Lee filters are out of stock, so I need to used those ones. :) Has somebody used them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the specs for both. If they're the same size, no reason you can't use them.

Answer (score 0):

[What I have found](http://www.2filter.com/prices/graduated_nd%20holders.html) for Hitech, Cokin, Lee and Schneider

**ADDED:**

I have bought them, its are suitable.